# How to check if element is fully visible in viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

```html
<section
  id="eigen"
  spyTarget="eigen"
  class="eigenes-template"
  style="min-height: 100vh"
></section>
```

I have a `<section>` with a `min-height` of `100vh`.

How can I check if the element is in the center of the window, so it covers the whole screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to "check if the element is in the center of the window" (I'm assuming you just care about the height and not width, though the approach will be the same), one way is to get the element's bounding box with the `getBoundingClientRect()` method. Use that to compute the vertical center coordinate; then compare with the center of the window.
For example:

```
const yourElement = document.getElementById('eigen');
const bBox = yourElement.getBoundingClientRect();

// this gets the vertical center coordinate of your element
const elementCenter = bBox.top + (bBox.height / 2);
// this gets the vertical center of the window (viewport)
const windowCenter = window.innerHeight / 2;
```

Then compare the values (use some tolerance since `window.innerHeight` only returns an integer).

If you want to check if the whole element is actually visible and not just centered, you can still use the bounding box. You would just check to see if `(bBox.top > 0 && bBox.bottom < window.innerHeight)`.